# How to filter ng-options on AngularJS select?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have something like this,

```
<select ng-model="person"
        ng-options="person.name for person in mv.people">
```

Now the people array has some members that I want to hide.  example:

```
{
   name: 'john',
   hide: true
}
```

How do I make sure these people aren't rendered as an option?

Comment: Have you tried to filter yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a `filter` just as you would if you were using `ng-repeat`.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ($scope) => {
    $scope.persons = [{
      name: 'John',
      hide: true
    }, {
      name: 'Jane',
      hide: false
    }, {
      name: 'Jeff',
      hide: false
    }, {
      name: 'Jim',
      hide: true
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <select ng-model="selectedPerson" 
          ng-options="person as person.name for person in persons | filter:{hide: false}">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for something like this.  What about this other case where I have a property but I need to pass it into a function and i want to hide based on what returns from that function?  Like this:

      {
         name: 'john',
         job: 'janitor'
       }


       function checkJob(job) {
         if (job === 'teacher') {
            return true;
         }
         return false;
       }

Comment: Don't do that in your view. When you call functions from your view in an `ng-repeat` or `ng-options` like that they get called multiple times due to the way the AngularJS digest cycle works. It will destroy performance. Instead build your collections in the controller and then use that in your view. That way you are only filtering your collection once and you get to decide when that happens.

Comment: ah ok thanks, maybe i'll call the function inside the controller and just have it pass a true or false before getting to the view then

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use the `filter` clause like this: `ng-options="person.name for person in people | filter:{hide:'false'}"`. In the future, you can also create a custom filter for your array and apply it in the `ng-options` clause. Below you have a working example.

Cheers!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
       "name": "john 1",
       "hide": false
    }, {
       "name": "john hidden",
       "hide": true
    }, {
       "name": "john 2",
       "hide": false
    }]
});

angular.module("myApp").filter('hidden', [function() {
    return function (object) {
        var array = [];
        angular.forEach(object, function (person) {
            if (!person.hide)
                array.push(person);
        });
        return array;
    };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
<select ng-model="person2" ng-options="person.name for person in people | filter:{hide: false}"></select>
<select ng-model="person2" ng-options="person.name for person in people | hidden"></select>
</div>
```